# plotting categorical data by row from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, categorical-data

I have some data showing a machine's performance. one of the columns is for when the pipe it makes fails a particular quality check causing the machine to automatically cut the pipe.  Depending on the machine and the way it's set up this happens around 1% of the time and I am trying to make a plot that shows the failure rate against time - my theory is that the longer some of the tools have been in use, the more failures they produce.

Here is an example of the excel file the machine makes every 24 hours.

[image: Data Snip]

The column "Cut Event" is the one I am interested in.  In the snip the "/" symbol indicates no cut was made, when a cut is made it the cell in that column will say "speed", "ovality" or "thickness" as a reason (in German).  What I want to do I go through a dataframe and only capture rows that have a failure, i.e. not a forward slash.

Here is what I have from reading through SO and other tutorials. The machine "speaks" German btw, hence the longer words,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fig = plt.gcf()

df = pd.read_excel("W03 tool with cuts and dates.xlsx",
                   dtype=object)


df = df[['Time','Cut_Event']]
df['Cut_Event'].loc[df['Cut_Event'] == 'Geschwindigkeitsschwankung'] = 'Speed Cut Event'
df['Cut_Event'].loc[df['Cut_Event'] == 'Kugelfehler'] = 'Kugel Cut Event'
df['Cut_Event'].loc[df['Cut_Event'] == '/'] = 'No Cut Event'

print (df)
```

What I am stuck on is passing these events over to be plotted. My python learned so far has been about plotting everything in a particular column of a numerical dataframe, rather than just specific events of categorical data and I am getting errors as a result.  I tried seaborn but got nowhere.

All help genuinely appreciated.

edit: Adding the dataset

```
Datum    WKZ_code    Time        Rad_t1   Not Important   Cut_Event
10 Sep  W03          00:00:00    100           250           /
10 Sep  W03          00:00:01    100           250           /
10 Sep  W03          00:00:02    100           250           /
10 Sep  W03          00:00:03    100           250           /
10 Sep  W03          00:00:04    100           250           /
10 Sep  W03          00:00:00    100           250           Speed Cut
```

Comment: You did not tell us what the desired output is. Maybe you are just looking for `df.Cut_Event.value_counts().plot(kind="bar")` but we don't know. If it is more complicated than that, a toy dataset as text, not as an image, would help you getting good answers.

Comment: Ok, I did that. Thanks for the tip

Comment: But we still don't know what the final graph should look like. Obviously, it is not a bar plot counting the occurrences of each `Cut_Event`. So, what is it? Link to a picture, if you cannot describe it well.

Comment: A simple line or scatter plot showing the cut events over time.

Comment: So, it seems the x-axis is time, and the y-axis is what? `/` or not `/`? Like bored and happy [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html)?

Comment: The y axis would be those cut events that are not "/".  I didn't list them all as the German word is horrendous & it varies by machine as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224528/discussion-between-exmatelote-and-mr-t).